# input field within dropdown list to narrow down search results is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

i am working on data filters of my website.I am implementing ajax based  interlinked dropdown filters.

for eg: in 1st dropdown user need to select country,then in 2nd dropdown states will be populated and after selecting state city list will be populated in third dropdown.

So my main concern is,i also want to give search facility within dropdown list to narrow down the search like in image[image].

here is my code:
**HTML**

```
<select name="country" id="country">
    <option>select country</option>

<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * from plus2_country ORDER BY country ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($row_count > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
             echo '<option value="'.$row['country_code'].'">'.$row['country'].'</option>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        '<option value="">Country not available</option>';
    }
?>
```

**JQUERY**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('#country').on('change',function(){
    var country_code = $(this).val();
    console.log(country_code);
    if(country_code){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'dependent.php',
            data:'country_code='+country_code,
            success:function(html){
                console.log(html);
                $('#state').html(html);
                $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 

            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#state').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');
        $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
    }
});
```

Just help me to implement text-box filter in dropdown.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.dropdown-menu input').click(function (e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(){

$('.dropdown-toggle b').remove().appendTo($('.dropdown- toggle').text($(this).text()));
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DZ7dc/)

Answer (score 0):

if you know about angularjs, you can do it easily by https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo

then, use this code:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex="60">
<label>state</label>
<md-select ng-model="selectedState" name="State" md-on-close="clearSearchState()" required>
<md-select-header>
      <input ng-model="searchState" type="search" placeholder="search...">
 </md-select-header>
 <md-optgroup label="stateItem">
 <md-option ng-value="stateItem" ng-repeat="stateItem in states | filter:searchState">{{stateItem.State}}</md-option>
   </md-optgroup>
 </md-select>
 <div ng-messages="addBranch.City.$error">
       <div ng-message="required">please feel the input</div>
 </div>
```

and in the controller define:

```
$scope.states=[{"State":"state1","ID":"1"},{"State":"state2","ID":"2"}];
$scope.searchState;
$scope.clearSearchState = function() {$scope.searchState = '';};
$element.find('input').on('keydown', function(ev) {ev.stopPropagation();});
```